# Create a scrollable view filled with a grid of dynamic buttons in Titanium

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

So what I am trying to do is:
I am loading data from a sqlite db and using it with a `while... isValidRow` to dynamically create a set of buttons, that I set a static `top` and `left`(or right). What I have found is that if I make the parent of all the buttons a `createView()` and set the `layout` to `horizontal`, this will create a nice grid.

```
var brandView = Ti.UI.createView({  
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    left: 0,
    layout: 'horizontal',
    textAlign: 'center'
});


while(rows.isValidRow()) {
     var dynamicButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        top: 10,
        left: 10,
        title: rows.fieldByName('name');
    });
    view.add(dynamicButton);

    rows.next();
}
```

The problem I am having is that sometimes there are more buttons than can be displayed on the screen at one time so the buttons extend down below the visible screen. So I turned the view to a `createScrollView`, and with the `layout` still set to `horizontal` (or vertical) it now places the butons side by side extending out beyond the screen to the side ( loosing the grid placements).
So my question is how can I make the view scrollable and have the buttons come out in a grid style formation?

Comment: Can you provide any types of Screenshot for understand what you want to perform...

Answer (score 2):

Try, This. I think this is helpful for you.

```
var brandView = Ti.UI.createScrollView({  
    height      : Ti.UI.FILL,
    width       : Ti.UI.FILL,
    contentHeight : "auto",
    backgroundColor : "transparent",
    layout      : "horizontal",
    horizontalBounce :false,
});


while(rows.isValidRow()) {
     var dynamicButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        top: 10,
        left: 10,
        title: rows.fieldByName('name');
    });
    brandView.add(dynamicButton);

    rows.next();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest your brand view in a scrollView, otherwise it will just scroll horizontally, also If you want your buttons to be centered in the screen don't set the `left` property just set the `top` property. Also, `textAlign` is not valid for `Titanium.UI.View`.

Here is an example that fills the whole screen, adds buttons to the grid, is centered, and is nested in a scroll view.

```
var scroller =  Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
});
var brandView = Ti.UI.createView({  
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    top: 0,
    layout: 'horizontal',
    textAlign: 'center'
});


while(rows.isValidRow()) {
     var dynamicButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
        top: 10,
        left: 10,
        title: rows.fieldByName('name');
    });
    view.add(dynamicButton);

    rows.next();
}

scroller.add(brandView);
```